# Django model order the results according to the entry date

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

How do order the DB query result according to the entry date?
I want to order the output from the latest entry added, using MySQL DB creation timestamp.

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    alias = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    goes_by = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    flag = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
    objects = models.Manager()



def getAuthor(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        result = list(Author.objects.filter(flag=0).values_list("name").order_by('-date'))
    else:
        pass
    return JsonResponse(result, safe=False)
```

Comment: Where have you created the `date` field? Also you don't need to use `models.Manager` for  objects it is automatically generated when migrate the models.

Comment: I do not have a `date` field in the table. I want to use MySql's timestamp; not creating my own timestamp column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    alias = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    goes_by = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    flag = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-date"]
```

Comment: Can I do it by using Mysql's entry time stamp? Without having to make a new column?

Comment: No, you have to make column dates for it to work

Comment: you can do this result = list(Author.objects.filter(flag=0).values_list("name").order_by('-date')) and you can do my answer